# Showing that all the singularities are removable

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I'm reading through a complex analysis textbook and I'm trying to do the following problem:

Suppose that $f \in H(\mathbb{C})$, $n$ is a positive integer and $f(n) = 0  $ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Show that all the singularities of $\frac{f(z)}{\sin(\pi z)}$ are removable.

Here is what I have so far:

$$\frac{f(z)}{\sin(\pi z)} = f(z).\frac{ \pi z}{\pi z \sin(\pi z)} = f(z).\frac{1}{\pi z}.(\frac{1}{1-(\frac{(z \pi)^{2}}{6}-\frac{(z \pi)^{4}}{120}+....)}) = f(z).(\frac{1}{\pi z}).(1+\frac{(\pi z)^{2}}{6}+...)= \frac{f(z)}{\pi z}+ \frac{f(z) (\pi)^{2} z}{6}+...$$

But, as we can see the coefficient of the $\frac{1}{z}$ term is not zero. So, how are the singularities removable? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(n)=0$ implies that $f(z)=(z-n)^{k}g(z)$ in some disk around $n$ where $g$ is analytic and $k$ is a positive integer. Now $\frac {f{(z)}} {\sin (\pi z)} =g(z)\frac {z-n} {\sin \pi z} (z-n)^{k-1}$ and $\frac {z-n} {\sin \pi z} \to \frac 1 {(-1)^{n} \pi}$ as $z \to n$ by L'Hopital's Rule. Hence $\frac {f{(z)}} {\sin (\pi z)}$ has  a finite limit as $z \to n$ which $n$ a removable singularity.

Comment: Thank you. I think where I went wrong is that I tried to do a Laurent expansion around $0$. I don't think that is possible as $0$ is not an isolated singularity